# Multiprocessing in django and Python code

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement multiprocessing in my application on windows system.

The scenario is :
From GUI, when i click "Run" button control comes to a python function(which is not a main function).

Now in this function I am running loop and reading/executing multiple file one at a time. I want this to happen in parallel.

But as multiprocessing.process() need `__name__ ='__main__'`, my function mentioned in "`target = function name`" in multiprocessing() is not being invoked.

How can I make it happen. If multiprocessing seems wrong way then any alternative way to improve code performance?

Adding Sample code(please note that this is just a psudo code where i have added high level code to understand the flow, please excuse any syntax error) :

urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from textapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('execute/',views.functiontomultiprocess),
    ...
    other urls
    ]
```

views.py:

```
def functiontomultiprocess(request):
nprocess = []
for doc in alldocs:
   p = multiprocess.Process(function2)
   p.start() # start process
   nprocess.append(p) 

 for  p1 in nprocess:
   p1.join()
```

Comment: Maybe a [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) can fit your needs

Comment: Unfortunately not @JPery. pool also need to be called from "__main__".

Comment: `if __name__ ==  '__main__'` is necessary only on Windows platforms. I assume that's your situation but no harm in checking, right?

Comment: I am not familiar with Django but I know Flask a bit. In Windows if I create a process or a pool in a function that handles a URL, even though all the code in the containing file is copied in the sub-process and execution is started from the top of the file, that function is not re-executed and there is not a problem. Perhaps it would help if you specify your environment and a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: @Booboo, added high level code flow.Please review and advise.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Are you developing a multithread or a background task? maybe is enough https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/
There you register and schedule your tasks and django runs

Answer (score 3):

This is too long to specify in a comment, so:

Again, I have no expertise in Django, but I would think this would not cause a problem on either Windows or Linux/Unix. However, you did not specify your platform, which was requested. **But moreover, the code you provided would accomplish very little because your loop creates a process and waits for it to complete before creating the next process. In the end you never have more than one process running at a time and thus there is no parallelism**. To correct that, try the following:

```
def functiontomultiprocess(request):
    processes = []
    for doc in alldocs: # where is alldocs defined?
        p = multiprocess.Process(function2, args=(doc,)) # pass doc to function2
        processess.append(p)
        p.start()
    # now wait for the processes to complete
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Or if you want to use a pool, you have choices. This uses the `concurrent.futures` module:

```
import concurrent.futures

def functiontomultiprocess(request):
    """
    Does it make sense to create more processes than CPUs you have?
    It might if there is a lot of I/O. In which case try:
    n_processes = len(alldocs)
    """
    n_processes = min(len(alldocs), multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=n_processes) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(function2, doc) for doc in alldocs] # create sub-processes
        return_values = [future.result() for future in futures] # get return values from function2
```

This uses the `multiprocessing` module:

```
import multiprocessing

def functiontomultiprocess(request):
    n_processes = min(len(alldocs), multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n_processes) as pool:
        results = [pool.apply_async(function2, (doc,)) for doc in alldocs] # create sub-processes
        return_values = [result.get() for result in results] # get return values from function2
```

**Now you just have to try it and see.**

Answer (score 2):

Task runner can use, in particular [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

By means of Celery it is possible to create "turn of tasks":

*my_task.py*

```
from celery import task

@task
def myJob(*args,**kwargs):
    # main task
    # . . .
```

*my_views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response as rtr

from .tasks import myJob

def view(request):
    # view
    # . . .
    myJob.delay(*args,**kwargs)
    return rtr('template.html', {'message': 'Job has been entered'})
```

The call of **.delay** will register * myJob * for performance by one of yours * celery *, but won't block representation performance.

The task isn't carried out until the worker doesn't become free therefore you should have no problems with number of processes.

Comment: this is not a main function so ur code will be bypassed..

Comment: You are absolutely right!  Task runner can use, in particular Celery.